# Grep: How do I print both the matching line and the pattern (using a file of patterns)?

Tags: regex, grep, cygwin

1. I am using cygwin.
2. I am grepping accross multiple files in a directory.
3. I am pulling regex patterns from a file.
4. I am writing the results to a file.
5. I would like each result line to also contain the matching pattern(s).

Currently, the command I'm using achieves 1-4 from above.
grep -E -i -f c:\patterns\patterns.txt c:\dir\*.csv > c:\results\results.csv

I know that if I add the -o parameter that it will just give me the matching pattern instead, and from there I could match up the line numbers for this output and for the output not using -o. But -o seems to take so much longer.

The pattern file itself is in excess of 5,000 lines. The files that I'm searching exceed a million lines.

**Sample Input:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/axltx3wcj9ina32/SampleInputFiles.zip

**Sample of Desired Output:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/ko3dz4hzhnqg8pm/output.csv.zip

How do I get the data I need?

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should show some sample input and the desired output.  How would you plan to tell the difference between the line and the match on the line?  Tab separated? Separate lines?

Comment: The files I'm searching are comma-separated text values for product information. The different csv files are in different column formats, and have differing numbers of columns. So if I formatted the output as  tab-separated, I could more easily unify the format by having the returned line in column A, tab-separated from the pattern match in column B. That seems like that should make sense, yes?

Comment: Please edit your question (you're always allowed to do that), and explain precisely and concisely what input you have, and what output you expect.  It depends on how contorted the CSV inputs can be; if you have to deal with commas inside quotes, you need a tool for handling CSV files ([csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix) springs to mind).  If your files are nice and simple, there may be advantages to a tab separated format.  But I still don't understand what you want as the output.

Comment: I added the requested information. Does that help clarify the question?

Comment: Probably, and no...What I was expecting (hoping for) was for a sample of say 5-10 lines of input (or 5-10 shortened/simplified lines of input) and 2-3 patterns, and the expected output (not more than N-1 of the N lines of input — so at least one of the lines should not be selected by the patterns), all written in the question.  I'll take a look at the Dropbox files later.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with t**wo grep and a join** based on the matching line number

```
grep -onf   /cygdrive/c/TEMP/exp_plain.txt  filelist.txt |sort -u > 1.txt

grep  -nf   /cygdrive/c/TEMP/exp_plain.txt  filelist.txt |sort -u > 2.txt

join  -t ":" 1.txt 2.txt
```